What is the biblical basis for refuting a literal Third Jerusalem Temple with Priests and Animal Sacrifices in the Millennium
Part of an answer to this question has prompted me to ask a question about the biblical basis for refuting a literal interpretation of the millennial reign of Christ Jesus. Here is  a partial quote of the Dispensational Futurist Interpretation:

In Revelation the thousand years are taken literally, assuming Israel on earth, and the church suspended above it in heaven for the entirety of this period. Old Testament priesthood, sacrifices, temple, and covenant figures are expected to be reinstituted beneath the heavenly suspension of the church for the duration, the Lord himself being, as is supposed, on earth reigning over Israel and the world.

One reason for challenging the literal interpretation is based on what happened when the Son of God died on the cross.  The veil of the temple was torn in two from top to bottom by an unseen hand.  See Matthew 27:51; Mark 15:38; Luke 23:45. This signifies (to me) that the temple priesthood and animal sacrifices, and even the temple itself, had become redundant when the Son of God laid down his life as the final, the ultimate sacrifice.  Why on earth would a literal temple, human priests, and animal sacrifices have to be reinstituted after Jesus cried out “It is finished!” (John 19:30)
Rather than ask for the biblical basis for this dispensational literal view (because that question has already been asked and answered), I am looking specifically for New Testament verses where Jesus himself contradicts such an idea.  I have already found some, but I seek input from Christians who disagree with a literal temple, priesthood and animal sacrifices in the millennium.

"refuting a literal interpretation of Revelation chapter 20" — refuting all of it, or certain parts of it, or what? ¶ The quoted section is hardly a literal interpretation of chapter 20, so is it that specific quotation, rather than the chapter itself, that you want to refute?

Good point, Ray. I will edit the question to make it clear that I seek to biblically refute the view (of some Christians) that there is to be a literal, third temple in Jerusalem, with priests and sacrifices resumed during the millennium.  The quotation regarding Revelation chapter 20 is an overview of how some people interpret parts of it. Had I wanted to delve into that chapter specifically, I would have gone to Biblical Hermeneutics. As it is, I seek the words of Jesus, and the other apostles, to form a biblical basis regarding that particular topic.

My apologies for not making my question clear, but thanks to everyone (so far) who has contributed.

Third Temple?They are several reasons why there is to be no Third Temple located in Jerusalem in the Mideast run by the Jews. Most of them deal with the purpose of a Temple.
1. The main purpose for a Temple was to offer Sacrifice for atoning for the sins of the people, corporately, or individually.
But now, with the eternal sacrifice of the Lamb of God, there is no need for any other, any more, sacrifice. (John 1:29, Behold the Lamb of God who takes away the sins of the world. John 19:30)
2. The Temple was the home of the Levitical priesthood who engaged in offering sacrifices, as well as judging civil matters.
It is abundantly clear in the N.T. that the Church folk are the "royal priesthood" now. (Peter wrote, But ye are a royal priesthood.) And the sacrifices God accepts are "a broken heart and humility." (See also Mark 12:33-34)
3. Another purpose of the Temple was holiday observance. Three times in a year, all males were to "appear before the Lord."
Obviously, with the Gospel going into all the world, all the believers could not fit into the Temple quad! Easter (Passover---fulfilled Passover!) is celebrated in every nation now, not just in a temple at Jerusalem.
4. The Tithe was to be brought to the Temple. There was the "harvest tithe", the "festival tithe", the "third year tithe" (for the poor), etc.
No way could the modern believers' tithes all fit in the Temple! It is more reasonable that each church handle the tithes in their congregations!
5. In the old Temple was situated the Ark of the Covenant which contained the written Law (Mosaic Law), spelling out the Covenant made with the Israelites.
However, in the N.T. the Law is written on our hearts, AND Jesus has made a New Covenant with believers (See the Last Supper narratives.) In fact, notice that the Second half of our Bible is called "The New Covenant", i.e. the New Testament!
6. But the most salient feature of the Temple was the Presence of God! The Shekinah Glory of God was resident over the Ark of the Covenant representing His effulgent, holy Presence.
As has been noted, the curtain in the Holy of Holies in the Second Temple was ripped in two, showing the absence of His Presence. (Matthew 27:51) And the N.T. is clear in teaching that believers are now the Temple of the Holy Spirit! God's Presence resides in each believer! Amazing!
Biblical Conclusion The book of Hebrews in the New Testament has made it abundantly clear that the New Testament era is a spiritual fulfilment of the Redemptive plans of God, which was typlified, symbolized, or patterned after the Old Testament Temple service. Once the fulfilment has occurred, there was no longer a need for a physical Temple---nor will there ever be anymore! (Colossians 2:16)

Believe me...a time is coming when you will worship neither on this mountain (Samaria temple), nor in Jerusalem (Temple mount). But you will worship the Father in spirit and in truth. For the Father seeks such to worship Him. (John 4:21-23)


At the outset, it needs to be categorically stated that Revelation chapter 20 says absolutely nothing about the point prompting this question: “Israel on earth, and the church suspended above it in heaven for the entirety of this period. Old Testament priesthood, sacrifices, temple, and covenant figures are expected to be reinstituted beneath the heavenly suspension of the church for the duration, the Lord himself being, as is supposed, on earth reigning over Israel and the world.”
That is pure interpretation of a collection of prophecies, yet one which seems blind to Rev. 20:11 which states that after the devil and his symbolic beasts are cast into the lake of eternally burning fire and brimstone:

"And I saw a great white throne and him that sat on it, from whose
face the earth and the heaven fled away; and there was found no place
for them.” Revelation 20:11 A.V.

Earth and heaven have no more place; they have fled away from that great white throne. So, if there was a third temple at Jerusalem built on it prior to that event, it will vanish too. But before anyone launches into objections, saying their prophetic time-line ‘allows’ for that, there are massive reasons – which alone – should get warning bells ringing at 100 decibels.
A reinstated building in Jerusalem that is like the Old Testament temple and where animal, and other sacrifices will be carried out, proclaims that the once-for-all perfect sacrifice of Jesus Christ was insufficient. The whole of Hebrews chapter 9 makes that clear. There is far too much in it to delve into here.
Also, such activity in a third, earthly temple will require a legitimate priesthood. That effectively declares the perfect priesthood of Christ to be insufficient.  Men of flesh and blood would have to be appointed to go back to a sacrificial system that Hebrews chapter 8 says was imperfect and could never make those who approached cleansed from sin.
Thirdly, are men to become mediators between other men on Earth, and God in heaven? That tramples on Hebrews chapters 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7 stating the only mediator between men and God being the glorified Christ in heaven.
Revelation is clear that when Christ returns, it will be to usher in the Day of Resurrection and Judgment, as chapter 20 shows, after which John “saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away, and there was no more sea.”
Dispensationalists might correct me if I am wrong here, but I gather they believe this present heaven and Earth will remain to eternity, and that it is upon this present Earth that they believe a literal temple will be built at Jerusalem.  They take as symbolic texts like this:

“But the day of the Lord will come as a thief in the night; in the
which the heavens shall pass away with a great noise, and the elements
shall melt with fervent heat, the earth also and the works that are
therein shall be burned up… Looking for and hasting unto the coming of
the day of God, wherein the heavens being on fire shall be dissolved,
and the elements shall melt with fervent heat. Nevertheless we,
according to his promise, look for new heavens and a new earth,
wherein dwelleth righteousness.” 2 Peter 3:7-13 A.V.

However, those who are amillennialists are horrified at dispensationalist interpretations that turn symbolic matters into literal, and literal matters into symbolic. Not least because that denies the total perfection of Christ’s sacrifice on the cross; not least because it makes the perfect priesthood of Christ insufficient; not least because it denies the one Mediator between God and men being the risen Christ.
No way can I detail all the New Testament verses that support exposure of the Dispensational, literal, earthly millennial view. I have listed a few chapters that need to be read in their entirety, and only a few specific verses. Whole books have been written exposing that view and I recommend this 632 page one: The Revelation of Jesus Christ by John Metcalfe  http://www.johnmetcalfepublishingtrust.co.uk/contact_us.htm

Paul probably gives the clearest verses as I’m sure you know. Such as 2 Cor 6:16, Eph 2:20-22, 1 Cor 3:16, etc. The best I can think of in the Gospels is John 2:19-22.

John 2:19 Jesus answered and said unto them, Destroy this temple, and
in three days I will raise it up. 20 Then said the Jews, Forty and six
years was this temple in building, and wilt thou rear it up in three
days? 21 But he spake of the temple of his body. 22 When therefore he
was risen from the dead, his disciples remembered that he had said
this unto them; and they believed the scripture, and the word which
Jesus had said.

Some other possible candidates are Matt 3:9, 16:18, Luke 3:8, and John 1:42. I'm approaching this from the perspective of the idea of a literal temple in the millennium,

I understand that John 2:21 does not support the idea of a literal temple during the millennium, but speaks of the resurrection of his body three days after he was crucified. Is that also your view?

Yes. I also am saying that along with the teachings of Paul these verses teach that the church makes up the spiritual body of Christ, and it is this temple that fulfills the OT prophecies, as all things are fulfilled in Christ.There is no need for a rebuilt temple in the millennium. The millennium represents the heavenly Jerusalem in my view (Heb 12:22, Gal 4:26)

Alan Fuller has already quoted John 2:19-22 where Jesus spoke prophetically of his resurrection, showing that the temple he spoke of was his body. Here are some other Bible verses where Jesus speaks of the temple and what happened after he laid down his body (only to take it up again).
Early in His ministry, Jesus prophesied that worshiping at the temple would soon be irrelevant, saying,

Believe me, woman, a time is coming when you will worship the Father neither on this mountain nor in Jerusalem” (John 4:21).

As Jesus left the temple court for the last time, He told the Jewish priests and rulers,

Look, your house is left to you desolate (Matthew 23:38).

A few days later when the Son of God died on the cross, the veil of the temple was torn in two from top to bottom by an unseen hand. This is recorded in three out of four Gospel accounts (Matthew 27:51; Mark 15:38; Luke 23:45). It signifies that the temple services had met their fulfilment in Christ, the ultimate sacrifice.
Jesus responded positively (in Mark 12:33-34) to one of the teachers of the law who said that it was more important to love God with all our heart, understanding and strength, and to love our neighbour as ourselves, than all burnt offerings and sacrifices.
As the “Lamb of God who takes away the sin of the world” (John 1:29), Jesus, by His one sacrifice, put an end to the ceremonies that were “a shadow of things to come”.  The reality is Christ Jesus (Colossians 2:16).
He is our High Priest forever, in the order of Melchizedek (Hebrews 5:6).  What need then for a physical temple on earth, with men who have to sacrifice animals?
